# Как удалять повторяющуюся строку, содержащую "Она:", и пропускать строку, содержащую "Вы:"?

Tags: delphi

Имею код, который удаляет вторую повторяющуюся строку:

```
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
With Memo1.Lines do
  begin
    for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
      for j := Count - 1 downto i+1 do
        if Strings[i]=' ' then continue else
        if Strings[i]=Strings[j] then
          Delete(j);
  end;
end;
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как применять удаление для повторяющейся строки, содержащей "Она:" в начале строки, и игнорировать повторяющуюся строку, содержащую "Вы:".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте через функцию pos. Если в строке есть слово "она", то удаляем, если нет, то проверяем следующую строку.